# Problems with overwriting overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with `overflow: hidden`, I had to set it for animations sliding, but I have to place logo between two containers on which this property is set on. I read many articles about this problem, but unfortunately, the solution wasn't straight accurate to my problem. I tried to use `z-index` and `!important` properties but that didn't work as well. Have you got any idea how to solve it?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100vw;
    grid-template-rows: 20vh 70vh 10vh;
}
nav{
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
section{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
footer{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <div>
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/" alt="">
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section></section>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

EDIT that's how to page looks like:
[image: example]
if you look at the top right of the page you'll see that logo is hidden and I what I want to achieve is to keep this visible.

Comment: The problem itself is unclear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. How should your website look like? Do you have an image of the desired look of the page?

Comment: @WaisKamal if you look at the snippet you'll see that logo is hidden. I want to somehow be able to show this without changing `overflow: hidden` on both containers.

Comment: @ArnoldGee I edited the post and inserted image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `z-index` can give you a more clear overview of layering your elements. Especialy in the future, when you expand your code and it gets more and more complex.

One way could be to remove the `overflow: hidden;` - this is the reason why your overlapping img is cut off.

But i think you'll need it because of sliding animations!?
So what about changing the HTML-elements?

Create a new content-wrapper with `position: relative;`.
Move the img outside of the `<nav>` into the new div `.content` together with the `<section>`, so it is not a target of the `overflow: hidden;` and give it an `id`. The Grid is still intact because the elements inside `.wrapper` are still 3 (the header-nav, the content-section and the footer)
Adjust  the positioning of the logo-img. So it is always same size (150px) so give `top: -75px;` thats the half of the height, so it is overlapping between header-nav and content-section at the middle.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100vw;
}
.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100vw;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 700px 100px;
}
nav{
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}
#floatingLogo{
    position: absolute;
    /* half of logo-height */
    top: -75px;
    right: 5%;
}
section{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
footer{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <div>
            content of &lt;nav&gt;
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
        <img id="floatingLogo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/" alt="">
        <section>
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
          content of &lt;section&gt;<br />
        </section>
    </div>
    <!-- footer inside or outside .content, your choice ;-) -->
    <footer>
      content of &lt;footer&gt;
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made a huge mistake because I changed units to absolute from relative. Is it possible to keep this responsive I mean that the logo won't change its own placement when you'll change size of the page?

Comment: Yes it is. If you make a content-wrapper-div with relative position and the logo + section inside it. i write another answer with snippet..